# Jquery id selector variable cannot bind to onchange

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables, dynamic, jquery-selectors

I have list of input area in the form with id like "contact1_title", "contact2_title", "contact3_title" ....

And I also have a list of selection in this form with id like "contact1_name", "contact2_name", "contact2_name" ....

I want to write a loop to dynamic bind the onchange function for the selections.

Here is my code:

```
for(var j=1;j<6;j++){                        
                    $('#contact'+j+'_name').change(function() {
                        alert(j);
                        //json.engineer is a json object
                        $('#contact'+j+'_title').val( json.engineer[this.selectedIndex-1].title );
                    });
}
```

When I change the selection, it always alert 6.

and title input area cannot be changed by select.

Does it mean the variable in javascript always change?

How can I bind an action dynamically?

I can hack it by using "this.name.split("_")[0]" but the code seems ugly.

Thanks in advanced.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Javascript closure inside loops - simple practical example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example)

Comment: Thanks. I didn't find this answer before.

Comment: That's one of the questions that can only be found if you know what the problem is ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrap your `change` functionality by closure:

```
for(var j=1;j<6;j++){     
    (function(j){                   
         $('#contact'+j+'_name').change(function() {
             alert(j);
             //json.engineer is a json object
             $('#contact'+j+'_title').val( json.engineer[this.selectedIndex-1].title );
         });
     })(j);
}
```

The problem was, when you click, your loop is already ended, so `j` is equal to `6`.

Comment: The event handler is already a closure. A more correct explanation would be: "Use an immediately executed function expression to create a new scope" (or something like that).

Comment: @FelixKling What about my new explanation?

Answer (score 1):

Another solution would be to pass the counter as event data:

```
for(var j=1;j<6;j++){                        
    $('#contact'+j+'_name').change({index: j}, function(event) {
        $('#contact' + event.data.index + '_title')
           .val(json.engineer[this.selectedIndex-1].title );
    });
}
```

Even better would be if you could avoid using a `for` loop, but that depends on your markup and whether you have control over the created elements since you probably have to adjust them to do so.

Comment: u changed event.data.indexj :)

Answer (score 0):

There is a closure already, use it efficiently.

```
for(var j=1;j<6;j++){                        
     $('#contact'+j+'_name').change(function() {
     var k=j;
     alert(k);
     //json.engineer is a json object
     $('#contact'+k+'_title').val( json.engineer[this.selectedIndex-1].title );
     });
}
```